# How can you specify a custom path for the babel loader in Webpack 1?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have a project that still uses webpack version 1 and I'm wondering if there's a way to specify a custom path for babel using require. Here's what I'm trying:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{ 
    test: /\.tsx?$/, 
    loaders: ["babel?query=require('./babel.dev')", 'awesome-typescript']
    }]
}
```

And I also tried using the webpack-combine-loaders package by doing the following:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{ 
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        loader: combineLoaders([
          {
            loader: 'babel',
            query: require('./babel.dev')
          },
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript'
          },
        ]),
      },
    }]
}
```

But neither solution works for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require.resolve` which works like require but returns the full path to the module instead of its content. It should not be a query but used instead of the loader name.

```
{ 
  test: /\.tsx?$/, 
  loaders: [require.resolve('./babel.dev'), 'awesome-typescript-loader']
}
```

`require.resolve` will not automatically add the `-loader` suffix, and you should not omit it in general, especially since it's no longer allowed in webpack 2.

Alternatively you can also configure [`resolveLoader.modulesDirectories`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolveloader), which webpack uses to look up loader imports.

```
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: [__dirname, 'node_modules']
}
```

With that you could use `'babel.dev'` as a loader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however using "require.resolve('./babel.dev')" gave me the following error: "babel.dev.js didn't return a function". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A loader must export a function, everything else is not a valid loader. What's the content of `babel.dev.js`?